# Get approvers of transaction using api?

Tags: iri-legacy-api

Given a transaction, how do I get a list of all of the transactions that reference it as their trunk or branch? I'm using pyota, but solutions in the other libraries would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 5):

There is the `findTransactions` api (with the `approvees` parameter) that return the list of all transactions directly approving the one (or the multiple) passed in parameter :

```
curl <NODE_URL> \
  -X POST \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'X-IOTA-API-Version: 1' \
  -d '{"command": "findTransactions", "approvees":"<TX_HASH>"]}'
```